# Custom HTML Helper for Validation Msg

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I wrote a custom HTTML Helper Tag for the output of Validation Messages.  It works properly, however it is always present.

`@Html.MyValidationMsg(m => m.FirstName)`

```
public static IHtmlContent MyValidationMsg<TModel, TProperty>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        var reqAttrib = memberExpression.Member
                      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), false)
                      .Cast<RequiredAttribute>()
                      .SingleOrDefault();

        var displayAttrib = memberExpression.Member
                      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
                      .Cast<DisplayAttribute>()
                      .SingleOrDefault();

        var errMsg = reqAttrib.ErrorMessage ?? displayAttrib.Name + " is required.";

        var content = new HtmlContentBuilder()
                 .AppendHtml("<div class=\"rvt-inline-alert rvt-inline-alert--standalone rvt-inline-alert--danger\">")
                 .AppendHtml("<span class=\"rvt-inline-alert__icon\">")
                 .AppendHtml("<svg aria-hidden=\"true\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" viewBox=\"0 0 16 16\">")
                .AppendHtml("<g fill=\"currentColor\">")
                .AppendHtml("<path d=\"M8,0a8,8,0,1,0,8,8A8,8,0,0,0,8,0ZM8,14a6,6,0,1,1,6-6A6,6,0,0,1,8,14Z\" />")
                .AppendHtml("<path d=\"M10.83,5.17a1,1,0,0,0-1.41,0L8,6.59,6.59,5.17A1,1,0,0,0,5.17,6.59L6.59,8,5.17,9.41a1,1,0,1,0,1.41,1.41L8,9.41l1.41,1.41a1,1,0,0,0,1.41-1.41L9.41,8l1.41-1.41A1,1,0,0,0,10.83,5.17Z\"/>")
                .AppendHtml("</g>")
                .AppendHtml("</svg>")
                .AppendHtml("</span>")
                .AppendHtml("<span class=\"rvt-inline-alert__message\" role=\"alert\" id=\"radio-list-message\">")
                .AppendHtml(errMsg)
                .AppendHtml("</span>")
                .AppendHtml("</div>");
        return content;
    }
```

How would I hide it on initial load of the Razor Page and when the field is invalid make it appear?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I guess var errMsg = reqAttrib.ErrorMessage ?? displayAttrib.Name + " is required."; this will always return some value. Try Below
var errMsg = reqAttrib.ErrorMessage != null ? displayAttrib.Name + " is required." : ""; Then return the content if errMsg.Length > 0

Comment: with javascript is the answer, but try to consider FluentValidation before proceeding on this path you are taking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIG THANKS to @itminus** for taking the time to get me on the correct path.

I ended up scratching this path entirely in favor of overriding jquery.validate.  Also manipulated the DOM with javascript / jquery to get the desired outcome.

Desired output for an error message:

```
<div class="rvt-inline-alert rvt-inline-alert--danger">
    <span class="rvt-inline-alert__icon">
        <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" aria-hidden="true">
            <g fill="currentColor">
                <path d="M8,0a8,8,0,1,0,8,8A8,8,0,0,0,8,0ZM8,14a6,6,0,1,1,6-6A6,6,0,0,1,8,14Z"/>
                <path d="M10.83,5.17a1,1,0,0,0-1.41,0L8,6.59,6.59,5.17A1,1,0,0,0,5.17,6.59L6.59,8,5.17,9.41a1,1,0,1,0,1.41,1.41L8,9.41l1.41,1.41a1,1,0,0,0,1.41-1.41L9.41,8l1.41-1.41A1,1,0,0,0,10.83,5.17Z"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="rvt-inline-alert__message" role="alert">Your Name is required.</span>
</div>
```

Code in `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` to do the magic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var settings = {
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "rvt-validation-danger", //around textbox on error
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

            var avg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
            avg.setAttribute("width", "16");
            avg.setAttribute("height", "16");
            avg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 16 16");
            avg.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");

            var g = document.createElement("g");
            g.setAttribute("fill", "currentColor");

            var p1 = document.createElement("path");
            p1.setAttribute("d", "M8,0a8,8,0,1,0,8,8A8,8,0,0,0,8,0ZM8,14a6,6,0,1,1,6-6A6,6,0,0,1,8,14Z");

            var p2 = document.createElement("path");
            p2.setAttribute("d", "M10.83,5.17a1,1,0,0,0-1.41,0L8,6.59,6.59,5.17A1,1,0,0,0,5.17,6.59L6.59,8,5.17,9.41a1,1,0,1,0,1.41,1.41L8,9.41l1.41,1.41a1,1,0,0,0,1.41-1.41L9.41,8l1.41-1.41A1,1,0,0,0,10.83,5.17Z");

            g.appendChild(p1);
            g.appendChild(p2);
            avg.appendChild(g);   

            var spanIcon = document.createElement("span");
            spanIcon.setAttribute("class", "rvt-inline-alert__icon");
            spanIcon.innerHTML += avg.outerHTML;

            var spanMsg = document.createElement("span");
            spanMsg.setAttribute("class", "rvt-inline-alert__message");
            spanMsg.setAttribute("role", "alert");
            spanMsg.innerHTML += error[0].innerHTML;           

            var c = document.createElement("div");
            c.setAttribute("class", "rvt-inline-alert rvt-inline-alert--danger");
            c.innerHTML += spanIcon.outerHTML + spanMsg.outerHTML;
            error.replaceWith(c);
        }
    };

    $.validator.unobtrusive.options = settings;
</script>
```

Comment: Nice work! awesome `$.validator.unobtrusive.options = settings;`

Answer (score 1):

There're two reason why the message always occurs.

1. As @Sonal Borkar said, the first reason is your `var errMsg = reqAttrib.ErrorMessage ?? displayAttrib.Name + " is required."` **makes it return some value even if there's no `[Required]` attribute docorated at all**.

   But don't change it to be `var errMsg = reqAttrib.ErrorMessage != null ? displayAttrib.Name + " is required."`, because the `reqAttrib` might be `null`. Instead, you can change the code as below :

   ```
   var errMsg = reqAttrib==null ? 
       "": 
       reqAttrib?.ErrorMessage ?? displayName + " is required.";
   ```
2. Secondly, you forgot to **check whether the current property has already got a value**. Suppose we have a property with a `[Required]` attribute decorated, and it does have a value assigned, then we should not display the required message like "xxx is requried".

Besides, there're some other bugs of `null object reference` in your code:

```
    var displayAttrib = memberExpression.Member
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)    
            .Cast<DisplayAttribute>()
            .SingleOrDefault();                                      

    var errMsg = reqAttrib.ErrorMessage ?? displayAttrib.Name + " is required.";
```

- the `reqAttrib` might be `null`, so the `reqAttrib.ErrorMessage` might throw errors.
- the `displayAttrib` might be `null` too
- if `displayAttrib` is null, we should fall back to`memberExpression.Member.Name`

To Fix the bugs, change your code as below :

```
    public static IHtmlContent MyValidationMsg<TModel, TProperty>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        var reqAttrib = memberExpression.Member
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), false)
                    .Cast<RequiredAttribute>()
                    .SingleOrDefault();

        var contentBuilder = new HtmlContentBuilder();
        // if the current property has no [Required] attribute, there's no need to display required message 
        if(reqAttrib == null ){return contentBuilder; }


        // check the value of current property 
        var compiled = expression.Compile();
        var model = (TModel) helper.ViewData.Model ;
        if(model == null){ 
            throw new Exception("No Model associated with the view !"); 
        }
        var propValue = (TProperty) compiled.Invoke(model);        
        // I just test nullable props here, you might custom it to fulfill your requirements, eg : whether the length of string matches
        if(propValue != null){ return contentBuilder; }


        var member = memberExpression.Member;
        var displayName= member
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
                    .Cast<DisplayAttribute>()
                    .SingleOrDefault()
                    ?.Name             // might be null
                    ?? member.Name;    // fall back
        var errMsg = reqAttrib==null ? 
            "": 
            reqAttrib?.ErrorMessage ?? displayName + " is required.";
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(errMsg)){ return contentBuilder; }
        return contentBuilder
                .AppendHtml("<div class=\"rvt-inline-alert rvt-inline-alert--standalone rvt-inline-alert--danger\">")
                .AppendHtml("<span class=\"rvt-inline-alert__icon\">")
                .AppendHtml("<svg aria-hidden=\"true\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" viewBox=\"0 0 16 16\">")
                .AppendHtml("<g fill=\"currentColor\">")
                .AppendHtml("<path d=\"M8,0a8,8,0,1,0,8,8A8,8,0,0,0,8,0ZM8,14a6,6,0,1,1,6-6A6,6,0,0,1,8,14Z\" />")
                .AppendHtml("<path d=\"M10.83,5.17a1,1,0,0,0-1.41,0L8,6.59,6.59,5.17A1,1,0,0,0,5.17,6.59L6.59,8,5.17,9.41a1,1,0,1,0,1.41,1.41L8,9.41l1.41,1.41a1,1,0,0,0,1.41-1.41L9.41,8l1.41-1.41A1,1,0,0,0,10.83,5.17Z\"/>")
                .AppendHtml("</g>")
                .AppendHtml("</svg>")
                .AppendHtml("</span>")
                .AppendHtml("<span class=\"rvt-inline-alert__message\" role=\"alert\" id=\"radio-list-message\">")
                .AppendHtml(errMsg)
                .AppendHtml("</span>")
                .AppendHtml("</div>");
    }
```

Comment: Bugs with my code, @itminus?!?!?!!  You must be outside your mind!!  :)   I don't quite understand what is going on with expressions and compile().  I need to learn more on that.  However, I'm not trying to change how the field is validated.  The default routine for `[Required]` works fine for me.  I am **only** trying to customize the HTML output generated from `<span asp-validation-for="Model.Property" class="text-danger"></span>` -- is there a better way?  As always -- THANKS!!!!

Comment: @Fraze I thought you was using the `MyValidationMsg<TModel, TProperty>()` by `@(Html.MyValidationMsg<YourModelType,YourPropertyType>(m=>lambda_to_get_your_property))`. So if property A already has a value, there's no need to display "A is required".

Comment: @Fraze the `Compile` and `Invoke` here are used to invoke the expression so that we can get the actual value of property.

Comment: you are correct.  I'm using like so: `@Html.MyValidationMsg(m => User.Name)`.  My only goal here is to change the HTML output by the validator helper to be that output from MyValidationMsg in my code.  If there is a better way to control the HTML output then maybe I'm just going about this wrong?

Comment: @Fraze Probably [this thread will help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#validation-error-ui-in-mvc)

Comment: This line `var propValue = (TProperty) compiled.Invoke(model);` from your post above causes a 'Null Ref' error because this is a create view and initially `User` is null.  However, after I hit Submit, MyValidationMsg is never invoked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184475/discussion-between-fraze-and-itminus).